# Convert negative digit in byte slice to int

Tags: java, go, base64, slice, bigint

I need help

Debezium(https://debezium.io/) convert decimal digits as integer in base64 string with precision as parameter in json In java it decoded like this example

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Base64;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String encoded = "lTBA";
        int scale = 4;
        final BigDecimal decoded = new BigDecimal(new BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded)), scale);
        System.out.println(decoded);        
     }
}
```

`"lTBA" = -700`

but in Golang I have some troubles in similar example

package main

```
import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    data, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString("lTBA")

    bigInt := new(big.Int).SetBytes(data).String()
    fmt.Println(bigInt)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3Xdq9x6B9V-
It returns `9777216`

Because when I use SetBytes in "math/big/Int" it set digit as positive always

```
// SetBytes interprets buf as the bytes of a big-endian unsigned
// integer, sets z to that value, and returns z.
func (z *Int) SetBytes(buf []byte) *Int {
    z.abs = z.abs.setBytes(buf)
    z.neg = false
    return z
}
```

Comment: If you are in control of the Debezium source connector, you also may set the "decimal.handling.mode" option to "double" or "string" (depending on the connector you're using) which might simplify consumption of the numeric values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constructor of Java's [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) expects the number in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) binary representation, while Go's [`big.Int.SetBytes()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.SetBytes) expects an unsigned integer value (in big-endian byte order):

> SetBytes interprets buf as the bytes of a big-endian **unsigned integer**, sets z to that value, and returns z.

What we can do is proceed using `Int.SetBytes()`, but if the number is negative, we have to transform it to the number the binary data represented in 2's complement. We can tell if it's negative if its first bit is 1 (which is the highest bit of the first byte).

This transformation is simple: if the input is represented using `n` bytes, construct a number using `n+1` bytes where the first is `1`, the rest is `0` (the max representable number using `n` bytes plus 1). Subtracting ([`Int.Sub()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Sub)) the input from this number will give you the absolute value of the number in 2's complement, so we just have to apply a negative sign on this number: [`Int.Neg()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Neg).

Scale can be applied by dividing ([`Int.Div()`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/#Int.Div)) the result by a number being `10`<sup>`scale`</sup>. We may construct such a number by appending `scale` zeros to a `1`.

Here is a `decode()` function that does all this. It's not optimized for performance, but it does the job:

```
func decode(in string, scale int) (out *big.Int, err error) {
    data, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(in)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    out = new(big.Int).SetBytes(data)

    // Check if negative:
    if len(data) > 0 && data[0]&0x80 != 0 {
        // It's negative.
        // Convert 2's complement negative to abs big-endian:
        data2 := make([]byte, len(data)+1)
        data2[0] = 1
        temp := new(big.Int).SetBytes(data2)
        out.Sub(temp, out)

        // Apply negative sign:
        out.Neg(out)
    }

    // Apply scale:
    if scale > 0 {
        temp, _ := new(big.Int).SetString("1"+strings.Repeat("0", scale), 10)
        out.Div(out, temp)
    }

    return
}
```

Example testing it:

```
n, err := decode("lTBA", 4)
fmt.Println(n, err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kLO0iuWdFl1)):

```
-700 <nil>
```

Comment: thank you for answer it very helpful
we did some fixes to improve speed and remove scale https://play.golang.org/p/BFZIKxOAp6-